# ClockPicker : Clock-style Timepicker for Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net, timepicker

How can i use this plugin with last jquery and without bootstrap? What i must include in my page? I don't wanna change de default style i putted on my website.

[Link Clockpicker](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?B83aD_dg)

Thanks!!

M.W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "jquery-clockpicker.min.css" and "jquery-clockpicker.min.js", it will work. In exemples section they have a [try it on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weareoutman/YkvK9/), if you check the sources, they use these files.

`jquery-clockpicker.min.js

jquery-clockpicker.min.css`

Comment: Not work for me.... i have asp.net page and jquery included... :(

Comment: Worked now. It was a javascript file that disturb it...